# Netstat shows open ports. What services are listening?

Tags: netstat, ports

Netstat (Windows 10) is showing certain services as "listening", but what service is listening on that port?

[image: netstat]

Any insights much appreciated.

Comment: `Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "LISTEN" } |  select @{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}},owningprocess, localaddress, localport, creationtime | where Process -eq "services" | Format-Table -AutoSize` might be a useful start.

No filter:
`Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "LISTEN" } |  select @{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}},owningprocess, localaddress, localport, creationtime | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: @HelpingHand put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `b` and `o` switches to see the executable name and PID (process ID that you can check in the Task Manager or `tasklist`.)

```
netstat -abo
```

> -b           Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port. In some cases well-known executables host multiple independent components, and in these cases the sequence of components involved in creating the connection or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called, and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient permissions.
>
> -o            Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.

Or for better/easier results, use Sysinternals's awesome **TCPView** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview